# Ring isomorphic to matrix division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So I am trying to show that if a ring $R$ is isomorphic to $M_n (D)$ as rings then $R=S \oplus … \oplus S $ (n times) as a left $R$-module where $S $ is a simple left $R$-module and $D$ is a division ring.

So if $R$ is isomorphic to $M_n (D)$ then every element of $R$ can be written essentially as $D^n \oplus … \oplus D^n $ (n times). Since $D$ is a division ring, $D^n $ is a simple left $R$-module.

So is it simply the case that $R = S \oplus … \oplus S$ where $S=\phi ^{-1}(C) $ where $C$ is one of the columns of $M_n(D)$?

Comment: The notation is confusing. $M_n(D)$ is equal to the direct sum of minimal left ideals.(which are simple modules) Using the isomorphism, same is true for $R$. These ideals are not really equal, but rather isomorphic as $R$-modules. So we can say we have an isomorphism $R\cong S\oplus...\oplus S$, not an equality.

Comment: How come when the isomorphism is an isomorphism of rings rather than of left modules. How does the direct sum sort of ‘carry over’ if we don’t know that the isomorphism is a module isomorphism?

Comment: We can't really talk about an isomorphism of modules anyway, because these are modules over different rings. But thing is, minimal left ideals are clearly preserved by a ring isomorphism.